# Vector dimensions and spatial dimensions

Tags: vectors, terminology, spacetime-dimensions

Are there any differences between vector dimensions and spatial dimensions? I have seen people talking about it a lot. And while talking about extra dimensions, they always bring these two terms up. So I thought if these terms are somehow synonymous or totally different?

Comment: Spatial space is the x, y, z of 3 dimensional space. A vector space is an n-dimensional abstract space, depending on the number of bases. A spatial space is one of the 3-dimensional vector space.

Comment: @ytlu That seems like an answer, not a comment.